# How to build Qt Quick 2d Renderer?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to follow http://doc.qt.io/QtQuick2DRenderer/qtquick2drenderer-installation-guide.html so we can use QtQuick in a device that doesn't have HW accel and OpenGL however, I'm trying to find where is the code mentioned in that article for the client-dummy but I can't find it on any package from http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.7/5.7.0/submodules/

Does anyone ever built that that can point me the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is a "submodule", more like a module of a submodule, that would be the `qtdeclarative` submodule:

http://download.qt.io/development_releases/qt/5.8/5.8.0-alpha/submodules/qtdeclarative-opensource-src-5.8.0-alpha.zip 
in `\src\quick\scenegraph\adaptations\software` or alternatively, you can get it from git: `git://code.qt.io/qt/qtdeclarative-render2d.git`

Comment: Thank you very much! I've been looking for weeks for this code and was always looking into the wrong place. Will now try to build that and use the renderer with QtWebKit. Thanks!